# Xcode 13 - Can't resolve Segmentation Fault: 11 Error. Help Needed

Tags: ios, xcode, ios15

Xcode 13 - Can't resolve Segmentation Fault: 11 Error. Help Needed
I have seen this issue after I have updated from Xcode 12 to 13. This issue is not reproducible on Xcode 12.

Any helpful comments will be much appreciated.

```
1.  Apple Swift version 5.5 (swiftlang-1300.0.31.1 clang-1300.0.29.1)
2.  
3.  While evaluating request ExecuteSILPipelineRequest(Run pipelines { Mandatory Diagnostic Passes + Enabling Optimization Passes } on SIL for LynxDispatch.LynxDispatch)
4.  While running pass #3799 SILFunctionTransform "PredictableDeadAllocationElimination" on SILFunction "@$sSo16UIViewControllerC12LynxDispatchE13mainContainerAC0f4ViewB0CSgvg".
 for getter for mainContainer (at /Users/hamidmahmood/Main/Projects-All/Work Projects/Lynx Dispatch/lynxdispatch-ios/LynxDispatch/LynxDispatch/Helpers/Extensions.swift:323:9)
Stack dump without symbol names (ensure you have llvm-symbolizer in your PATH or set the environment var `LLVM_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` to point to it):
0  swift-frontend           0x00000001097cd6f7 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&, int) + 39
1  swift-frontend           0x00000001097cc688 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 248
2  swift-frontend           0x00000001097cdd06 SignalHandler(int) + 278
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff20473d7d _sigtramp + 29
4  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 18446603339974623904
5  swift-frontend           0x0000000105534a43 swift::recursivelyDeleteTriviallyDeadInstructions(llvm::ArrayRef<swift::SILInstruction*>, bool, llvm::function_ref<void (swift::SILInstruction*)>) + 2275
6  swift-frontend           0x0000000105534c2b swift::eraseUsesOfInstruction(swift::SILInstruction*, llvm::function_ref<void (swift::SILInstruction*)>) + 203
7  swift-frontend           0x00000001052dde47 (anonymous namespace)::PredictableDeadAllocationElimination::run() + 6855
8  swift-frontend           0x000000010530a7b9 swift::SILPassManager::runFunctionPasses(unsigned int, unsigned int) + 4409
9  swift-frontend           0x000000010530692b swift::SILPassManager::executePassPipelinePlan(swift::SILPassPipelinePlan const&) + 155
10 swift-frontend           0x000000010532120c swift::SimpleRequest<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest, std::__1::tuple<> (swift::SILPipelineExecutionDescriptor), (swift::RequestFlags)1>::evaluateRequest(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&, swift::Evaluator&) + 60
11 swift-frontend           0x000000010530f005 llvm::Expected<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest::OutputType> swift::Evaluator::getResultUncached<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest>(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&) + 469
12 swift-frontend           0x00000001053113bb swift::runSILDiagnosticPasses(swift::SILModule&) + 187
13 swift-frontend           0x0000000104a5a6de swift::CompilerInstance::performSILProcessing(swift::SILModule*) + 62
14 swift-frontend           0x0000000104905d59 performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 1161
15 swift-frontend           0x00000001048f7d46 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 13494
16 swift-frontend           0x0000000104839a48 main + 1032
17 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff20449f3d start + 1
18 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000010f start + 18446603339974795731
error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'LynxDispatch' from project 'LynxDispatch')
```

Comment: Did u found any solution?

Comment: @steveSarsawa Honestly did not follow up on this solution, looks like this problem was resolved for me. Looks I upgrading Xcode resolved this issue for me.

Comment: Currently which XCode version are u using? @Hamid

Comment: @steveSarsawa Currently I 'm using Xcode 13.2.1